# Can't open .odt files created on Google Drive

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, google-drive

When I try to open a .odt file that I was created with Google Drive on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, I get `Unknown error. Google replied "`. Is there a work-around?

Comment: Did you try downloading the file and then opening it with LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Drive cannot be accessed from a LibreOffice version running on a Gnu/Linux distro.

Setting up a connection can be done by saving a document to a remote server or opening a remote file for the first time.

```
 First open a document or create a new one.
 Click File.
 Click Open Remote File.
 Click Add Service in the Remote Files dialog.
 When the File Service dialog appears, make sure Google Drive is the selected choice in the Type drop-down menu.
 If it is not, click the arrow and choose it from the menu.
 Next, enter the email address of the Google account in the user field.
 For the Password field, enter your Google password.
 Put a check in the Remember Password check box, if you are going to continually use this account.
 If you want a different title for your account, then change what is in the label field.
 For your first account, you will be asked to establish a master password. Create one. Then retype it in the next field.
```

This is how you access your account after setting it up.

```
Click File.
Click Open Remote File.
You may need to enter the master password that you established while setting up the account.
Next, click the service drop-down menu and select the Google Drive account, if it is not already the selected account.
You may need to enter your Google password again, if you didn’t put a check in the Remember password check box during set up.
```

Saving a document to Google Drive

```
Click File.
Click Save to Remote Server.
You may need to enter the master password that you established while setting up the account.
You may need to enter your Google password again, if you didn’t put a check in the Remember password check box during set up.
Select the account from the Service drop-down menu.
Then give the document a name.
Choose the File format you wish.
Then click the Save button. If you selected a format other than an OpenDocument one, a dialog will appear asking you to confirm that choice or save the document as an OpenDocument.
```

Comment: I tired this but I never get the PIN to log in.

Comment: @Svetlana Belkin: Choose whether or not to require PIN entry. Open the Google Admin app . If necessary, switch to your administrator account: Tap Menu Menu and then Down Arrow Down Arrow to choose another account. If necessary, enter your Google PIN. Tap Menu -- and then Settings. Tap Ask for PIN to turn it on or off.

Comment: My account isn't an admin one and I don't who would be the admin since I linked my Fastmail account to Google.